# Magento 2.3.4 - Call phtml file within CMS block

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, cms-block

I'm trying to call the following phtml file into a CMS block.

Phtml file location

```
app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe_footer.phtml
```

I tried using

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe_footer.phtml"}}
```

And it doesn't show up on the page.

How do I get it to show on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I ave seen you code and I found below issue with your code please check it once.

you have called wrong class in block you added in cms page.

Please correct it with below right code.

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe_footer.phtml"}}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thank you,

Nirav Patel

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesn't work